# Javascript load more with parse query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm dealing with a problem.
I have a simple query in Parse.com Javascript SDK which runs when the pages loads.

```
function start() {
    Parse.initialize("ID", "JSKEY");
    var query = new Parse.Query("events");
    query.ascending("eventDate");
    query.limit(20);
    //query.skip(0); maybe?
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var controlEv = results[i];

                var nameHTML = document.createTextNode(controlEv.get('name'));
                document.getElementById('theName').appendChild(nameHTML);
            }


        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}

<body id="top" onload="start();">
  <p id="theName"></p>
```

So now with this query i get 20 event results from parse.com
But the table rows are lets say 100... 
I want to make a button that will load the next 20 and if i push it again it will load the next 20 etc.

Does anyone have any solution about it or dealt with it??

I havent tried anything but i guess it has something to do with `query.skip` and `query.limit`

Comment: what you want is simple pagination, there are plenty of tutorials available online, and yes you are correct, you will use Skip and Limit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>   
    <script>
    var x = 20;
    var y = 0;
function start() {

    Parse.initialize("ID", "KEY");
    var query = new Parse.Query("events");
    query.ascending("eventDate");
    query.limit(x);
    query.skip(y); 
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var controlEv = results[i];

                var nameHTML = document.createTextNode(controlEv.get('name'));
                document.getElementById('theName').appendChild(nameHTML);


            }
            x = x + 20;
            y = y + 20;
console.log(results.length);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
</script>
    </head>
  <body id="top" onload="start();">
    <p id="theName"></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="start()">Click Me!</button>
   </body> 
</html>
```

I think this is the best way so far and you dont have to worry also about limit 10000 that parse has.